# Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with install4j 6.1.4 and JRE 1.8.0_121

Tags: install4j

We upgraded to latest JRE/install4j for our minor upgrade installer, and we started getting the following error when we try to use install4j API:

```
2017-02-17 19:29:42 SEVERE:  #{14} [StandardContext.loadOnStartup] Servlet [ConfigServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.setWindows95(Z)V
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.setWindows95(Native Method)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Misc.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.windows.WinEnvVars.getenv(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallerUtil.is64BitWindows(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.Util.is64BitWindows(Unknown Source)
...
```

We get the same error when we try to launch the uninstaller:

```
Exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.setWindows95(Z)V
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.setWindows95(Native Method)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Win32UserInfo.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.UserInfo.isAdminGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.api.Util.isAdminGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.initAdminRights(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.initCommandLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the API JAR file (i4jruntime.jar) and the native library (i4jinst.dll). It seems that you have an old version of i4jruntime.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Interestingly, i4jinst.dll in the .install4j folder seems to be from the earlier version where as i4jruntime.jar seems to be the latest version. Should'nt this dll also be replaced during upgrade?

Comment: in which .install4j folder? When you run an update installer, these files will be replaced. The stacktrace contains methods that are not in the current version anymore.

Comment: Base Installer created using i4j v6.0.1
SHA1 hash of file i4jinst.dll:
03 e9 b2 04 a4 75 6b 21 0a b8 15 4a 42 72 2c 24 16 5d 5e 7e
SHA1 hash of file i4jruntime.jar:
70 d5 bb 97 29 38 12 be 53 09 66 da f0 20 46 ca 15 2d 34 4d
-
Minor Upgrade created using i4j v6.1.4
SHA1 hash of file i4jinst.dll:
62 cd d7 fc 7d ff 20 4f 24 02 e3 5b a6 df ab 47 f2 d9 7a 7c
SHA1 hash of file i4jruntime.jar:
70 d5 bb 97 29 38 12 be 53 09 66 da f0 20 46 ca 15 2d 34 4d
-
NOTE: 
InstallDir/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar -> Unchanged
InstallDir/.install4j/i4jinst.dll -> Changes to version dated 11/29/2016

Comment: i4jruntime is not be unchanged after an upgrade from 6.0.1 to 6.1.4, it changes in every version. Do you maybe use an "Add-on installer"?

Comment: That's right. The Regular installer was created using install4j v6.0.1. The Add-On installer was created using install4j v6.1.4. Once we install the Add-On install on top of the regular install, our service won't start and throws the UnsatisfiedLinkError mentioned above.

Comment: An add-on installer does not update the runtime, I would recommend to use a regular installer.

Comment: Actually I don't need these updated at all. Problem is that one seems to be getting updated by the Add On Installer and other isn't.. We've never had this issue earlier and it seems to surface with latest install4j.

Comment: We've addressed the issue for now by downgrading install4j to 6.0.4.

Comment: We have reproduced the problem and fixed it in the current build. You can contact support for an interim build where this is fixed or wait until 6.1.5.

Comment: great. Thanks! We will wait till 6.1.5.