# How do i make my install4j installer replace i4jinst.dll to avoid UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: install4j

I'm running into similar problem as described here - [Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with install4j 6.1.4 and JRE 1.8.0_121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300039/getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-install4j-6-1-4-and-jre-1-8-0-121)

We have an application installer writen with install4j.
Recently we upgraded from 6.0.1 to 8.0.8.

After updating application installed with 6.0.1 installer with installer build by 8.0.8, the i4jinst.dll does not get replaced and the unistaller fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError.

- Files.log contain entry for this file:

```
<entry name=".install4j\i4jinst.dll" shared="false" uninstallMode="2"/>
```

- Installation.log does **not** contain anything about this file.

How can i tell install4j to upgrade this file (i4jinst.dll) during upgrade of the application?

Comment: On the "Install files" action, is the "Install runtime" property selected?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055032/how-do-i-make-my-install4j-installer-replace-i4jinst-dll-to-avoid-unsatisfiedlin#comment111518372_63055032) suggestion, i've checked the "install files" step - there was special filter that was ignoring whole **.install4j** folder during update - added that to the filter expression and all is working.

Thanks a lot